# Is there a way to get size of data commited to database by LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing an example program which will test the database connection performance (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL).

All data is prepared and queued using: `InsertOnSubmit()` then pushed to DB using:

```cs
DateTime dbInsertStartTime = DateTime.Now;
db.SubmitChanges() ;
DateTime dbInsertStopTime = DateTime.Now;
```

I am able to get time of operation in milliseconds.

How do I get size of data which is *queued* or *written* to DB?

The program allows the user to define number of data (like 10 data type A, 4 type B etc.) to be generated, not amount as it should simulate real working conditions.

Therefore I would like to know how many data were generated.

Comment: You need to use a Stopwatch to time.

Comment: You might want to consider profiling tools offered by the databases, they are supposed to do this sort of things.

Comment: I would agree with using Stopwatch. There's a comparison of different timing techniques at http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.se/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html. Note that DateTime.Now calculates timezone differences, and therefore is not suitable when measuring time, that's why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I changed your title to avoid using a tag in the title. There's no point in prefixing your title with tags, instead try to include them in the title as a whole. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: What does "how many data were generated" even mean? The number of records? (You could probably inspect an EF context to look for modified / new entities, not sure about a raw connection.) How many bytes were transferred between the client and the DB? (This is probably best done outside the application by having a TCP proxy measure this.)

Comment: @millimoose I need to know how many bytes were transfered to db.
As I see from comments only external tools may provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` has a [`GetChangeSet()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) which returns a [`ChangeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.aspx) containing all the objects that have been added, modified or removed - one collection for each. With a little more Linq you can separate them into types and count them to see how many of each type there are.

Also, as It'sNotALie notes in the comments, when timing operations you should really use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime`; it has much better precision.

#### Note:

This answer refers to Linq-To-SQL's `DataContext`. For those using Entity Framework, `DbContext.SaveChanges()` returns an `int` indicating how many entities were affected, and you can use the `SavingChanges` event to inspect the [`ObjectStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx) and get object states that way.